# Connectivity manager gives null pointer exception in android

Tags: android, connection, android-location

My Code to check internet connection.

```
public boolean internet() {

    boolean flag = false;
    //context=FindPeopleFragment_revice.this;
//  FindPeopleFragment_revice.context = this;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (info[0].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                    || info[1].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                flag = true;

            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

    }
    return flag;
}
```

When I Turn off/On **Location API** at that time **Exception** Arise at a point:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Ecexption Arise:

```
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169): Process: info.staffmark, PID: 29169
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at info.staffmark.FindPeopleFragment_revice.internet(FindPeopleFragment_revice.java:1210)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at info.staffmark.FindPeopleFragment_revice.onLocationChanged(FindPeopleFragment_revice.java:1822)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.jg$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-25 12:47:25.184: E/AndroidRuntime(29169):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

OnLocation Change method:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  internet = internet();
        internet = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

        Log.d("Net Status is", "Net is " + internet);   
        if (internet) {

        Double Latitude=location.getLatitude();
        Double Longitude=location.getLongitude();

        variable.CurrentLat=Latitude;
        variable.CurrentLong=Longitude;

        Log.d("Latitude is", ""+Latitude);

        Log.d("Longitude is", ""+Longitude);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(Latitude, Longitude, 10);

            for (Address address : addresses) {
                if(address.getPostalCode()!=null){
                       // Log.d("licality",address.getLocality());
                        Log.d("postalcode","Postal Code is"+address.getPostalCode());
                        variable.currentZip=address.getPostalCode();

                        internet = internet();
                        if (internet) {

                            if(variable.LocationType.equals("")){
                                internet=internet();
                                if(internet){
                                if(LocationType.equals("")){
                                    Location(); 
                                }
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet service is not available in your device.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }else{
                                 internet=internet();
                                 if(internet()){
                                     Data();     
                                     ShowMarkerMap();
                                 }else{
                                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet service is not available in your device.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 }}

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Internet service is not available in your device.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     }

    }
```

Exception arise at On location change method while checking internet connection.

I confuse how to solve this.

Please  help me to solve this, Thanks.

Comment: Include the stack trace...  Have you requested permission to access network state?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: What is line `FindPeopleFragment_revice.java:1210`?

Comment: This is on 1210:  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

Comment: I think `getActivity()` is returning null. Can you check that and fix that?

Answer (score 0):

in case this code is in the oncreate() of your fragment, try putting it in onActivityCreated().
My guess: getActivity returns null.
You should atleast put your stacktrace in your question thought.

Check : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

It tells you:
 "Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point. If you want to do work once the activity itself is created, see onActivityCreated(Bundle)."

Comment: Please help to solve this issue.If you have any idea

Comment: can u post your OnLocationChanged code ? And where do you set your LocationChangedListener ? in Oncreate ?

Comment: I am using fragment so onCreateView() is called

Comment: i still guess you set you listener at the wrong position. try putting it in onactivitycreated.